# Split a comma-separated Key Value Pair with both quoted

Tags: c#, string, split

I have a string in following format

```
"Name":"ABC","Address":"Street1,Street2","City":"Pune"
```

I want the output as

```
Name = ABC
Address = Street1, Street2
City = Pune
```

The code I am using is

```
 public string[] GetData(string op)
{
    MDB result = new MDB();
    var split = op.Split(':');
    string[] keyValue;
    foreach (string s in split)
    {
        keyValue = s.Split(',');

        try
        {
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = result.GetType().GetProperty(keyValue[0]);

            if (propertyInfo != null)
            {
                propertyInfo.SetValue(result, Convert.ChangeType(keyValue[1], propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

However when I split the text at "," I get following result

```
Name= ABC
Address = Street1
```

How can I get Street2 in address?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?  Code samples?

Comment: Can you show your code (reproducable sample) and what is not working?

Comment: I think someone with 4,5k rep should know how to ask

Comment: without code sample, nobody can help you. when I use string split, i get an array of strings.. you have to explain more. I'm also wondering where you get that high rep...

Comment: *I have a string in following format*.. seems to me like *multiple* strings.. you need to post your code

Comment: @fubo It seems his rep is mostly from a few well-timed high-profile question / answers regarding rather basic things... I'd say this is one example of someone's rep not following with question / answer quality.

Comment: @fubo: It's really my bad. Updated question now.

Comment: Does your string contain the double quotes?

Comment: @PaulF: Yes. It contains the double quotes.

Comment: As I cant answer I will explain. My first idea was to first replace the "," sequence with something like ";" and then split on ;. But I have just found an override to Split - if you first use Split(new Char[] { ',' }, 2) the result will be limited to 2 substrings "Name":"ABC" and "Address":"Street1,Street2" - you can then split each substring on ':'.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GXG6kj

Comment: Your source string looks like Json.  Why not use a Json deserializer to convert it to an object?

Comment: Here's a sample that uses JSon:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/ijvmdB

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: Thanks for your response. The string content is not consistent. It is not working for ""Name":"ABC","Address":"Street1,Street2","City":"Pune""

Comment: @PaulF: Thanks for your proposed solution. But as I mentioned in my reply tp ChrisDunaway, the content might change.

Comment: @Ram: have you tried my original solution - replacing "," with ";" and splitting on ; (NOTE that it is double quote-comma-doublequote that is being replaced NOT comma only) - uncomment the commented out line in the dotnedfiddle & comment out the following line.

Comment: Just change the class to include all the possible properties and it should work (i. e. add City to the class and any other possible properties).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like JSON,  some simple deserialization would get the job done

```
public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
    }

    private static void jsonDeserialize()
    {
        var json = "{\"Name\":\"ABC\",\"Address\":\"Street1,Street2\",\"City\":\"Pune\"}";

        User user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);
        Console.WriteLine("Name = "+ user.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Address = " + user.Address);
    }
```

Result:

```
Name = ABC
Address = Street1,Street2
```